# Edit content inside iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, storyblok

I'm interested in knowing how you'd go about creating a website builder through an iframe.

One software I've noticed enables you to do this is Storyblok - edit the page through an iframe and it updates the site.

As a side project, I want to build a website editor that edits the site through an Iframe - but I'm kind of lost where to begin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Post any code attempt you have made.

Comment: @fakethesnake Lots of ways to achieve this, it's too broad theme. I suggest read about iframes and learn a bit of javascript to get started. If you have some problem write here ;)